# Copying multiple sub directory content from a parent directory into a new directory

Tags: ant

I have a directory called config under each of the subfolders of a parent directory lets x. I want copy all the config directories from each of the sub directories of x into a new directory. I want to do through Ant since i dont want to introduce a new technology into build script. Looks foreach and for does the operation at the file level but not the directory level. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using FOR from the command line instead of ANT, try FOR /? for help, it's easy...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, using `copy` task should solve your problem:

```
<copy todir="${dst.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/config/**"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```